# create-react-app not found after react install

Tags: reactjs

Attempting to start a React App and get this.

```
ZeroCalm$ create-react-app hello-world
-bash: create-react-app: command not found
```

I attempt to install and get:

```
ZeroCalms-MacBook-Pro:reactProjects ZeroCalm$ sudo npm install create-
react-app
Password:
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'/Users/ZeroCalm/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit 
this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'/Users/ZeroCalm/package.json'
npm WARN ZeroCalm No description
npm WARN ZeroCalm No repository field.
npm WARN ZeroCalm No README data
npm WARN ZeroCalm No license field.

+ create-react-app@1.5.2
added 97 packages in 6.312s
```

Attempt to create a react app:

```
ZeroCalms-MacBook-Pro:reactProjects ZeroCalm$ create-react-app hello-
world
-bash: create-react-app: command not found
```

Mac OS High Sierra version 10.13.1 / npm v- 5.6.0 / node v8.9.4

Comment: `sudo npm install create-react-app -g`. u forget `-g`

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-new-app.html

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `global` tag to your `npm install` command.

`sudo npm install -g create-react-app`

This saves `create-react-app` as a global package that you can use anywhere ([see docs for more info about npm install here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)).

Comment: Thanks, but I am still receiving the same "not found" message.

Comment: It's the same message, saying that there is `no such file or directory`?

Was there any different output?

Comment: Same output:ZeroCalm$ create-react-app hello-world
    -bash: create-react-app: command not found

Comment: What's the output after you run `sudo npm install -g create-react-app`? Is it successful?

Comment: ZeroCalms-MacBook-Pro:reactProjects ZeroCalm$ sudo npm install -g create-react-app
Password:
/Users/ZeroCalm/.npm-packages/bin/create-react-app ->       Same Output.

Comment: Can you try looking at this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/138)? Someone had a similar problem.

It seems like there was an issue with their `/user/local/bin/`.

Comment: that last link you sent me, I found the solution there.  MY $Path needed help.  Thanks.  How do I mark this as solved?

Comment: Awesome!
I think there's a green checkmark that you can click to mark an answer as correct.